# Tailwind CSS not adding translate styling

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I've got a `<div>` which is toggling between `translate` classes like so:

```html
<div class={`w-96 fixed top-16 bottom-0 left-0 transition-transform -translate-x-${show ? '0' : '96'}`}>
```

And Tailwind is just not applying this style, and I don't understand why. The class is added to the element, but not the styling.

[image: class]

The styling for all the other classes is added, except for `-translate-x-96`.

This is my `app.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Does this work: `${show ? '-translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-96'}`?

Comment: Just remove the image upload element from the Ask Question page if I'm not allowed to upload pictures, also it's hosted by SO so it's not llike it's going to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind v3 generates styles for classes it finds by scanning the files specified in `content` field in `tailwind.config.js`. This means that the classes should be present in the code as-is and should not be constructed by concatenation.

From https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth:

> The way Tailwind scans your source code for classes is intentionally very simple — we don’t actually parse or execute any of your code in the language it’s written in, we just use regular expressions to extract every string that could possibly be a class name.

The fix in this case is to specify the full class name in both branches of the ternary operator:

```
`${show ? '-translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-96'}`
```

Comment: Yep that was it, thanks! Learned something new about Tailwind, include full class names.